# PosgreSQL partition table randomly experiences very slow query runtimes times when benchmarked

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, database-partitioning

We decided to partition a table in our database by customer ids creating roughly 1000 partitions. However we have seen that when executing many queries (hundreds to thousands) on the partitioned table, query runtimes will sometimes exponentially increase.

Using pg bench, we ran an sql file containing 2080 of the following query:

```
select id from partitioned_table where partitioned_key = 1 limit 1;
```

which accesses one partition on the partition table. Here are the results:

```
progress: 13.0 s, 5.0 tps, lat 190.808 ms stddev 4.059
progress: 14.0 s, 5.0 tps, lat 219.025 ms stddev 21.408
progress: 15.0 s, 3.0 tps, lat 218.078 ms stddev 18.176
progress: 16.0 s, 4.0 tps, lat 328.409 ms stddev 169.879
progress: 17.0 s, 5.0 tps, lat 213.951 ms stddev 11.566
progress: 18.0 s, 5.0 tps, lat 194.437 ms stddev 5.019
progress: 19.0 s, 5.0 tps, lat 191.391 ms stddev 6.559
progress: 20.0 s, 3.0 tps, lat 265.294 ms stddev 58.411
progress: 21.0 s, 3.0 tps, lat 349.060 ms stddev 63.183
progress: 22.0 s, 5.0 tps, lat 224.450 ms stddev 45.912
progress: 23.0 s, 5.0 tps, lat 203.634 ms stddev 14.167
...
scaling factor: 1
query mode: simple
number of clients: 1
number of threads: 1
duration: 30 s
number of transactions actually processed: 147
latency average = 205.337 ms
latency stddev = 47.148 ms
initial connection time = 3.221 ms
tps = 4.870029 (without initial connection time)
```

In comparison when we ran the equivalent query on the same table that wasn’t partitioned these were the results:

```
progress: 12.0 s, 6.0 tps, lat 160.004 ms stddev 7.696
progress: 13.0 s, 6.0 tps, lat 159.690 ms stddev 8.876
progress: 14.0 s, 6.0 tps, lat 156.359 ms stddev 5.159
progress: 15.0 s, 6.0 tps, lat 164.488 ms stddev 5.685
progress: 16.0 s, 7.0 tps, lat 161.612 ms stddev 7.227
progress: 17.0 s, 6.0 tps, lat 159.191 ms stddev 5.921
progress: 18.0 s, 7.0 tps, lat 152.827 ms stddev 9.228
...
scaling factor: 1
query mode: simple
number of clients: 1
number of threads: 1
duration: 30 s
number of transactions actually processed: 186
latency average = 161.972 ms
latency stddev = 16.605 ms
initial connection time = 3.291 ms
tps = 6.173878 (without initial connection time)
```

In particular at the 21st second progress report, average transaction times almost double compared with other progress reports. This doesn’t occur for the non-partitioned table.

We have observed in other testing that query runtimes will momentarily go from ~1ms to in the 100-s ms and sometimes into the seconds range and then improve again. When running the same benchmarking from our Elixir App (we use Ecto as our ORM) this is what we observed (at a per query level):

```
...
[debug] QUERY OK source=“partitioned_table” db=0.3ms idle=8.5ms
SELECT n0."id" FROM "partitioned_table" AS n0 WHERE (n0."partitioned_key" = $1) LIMIT 1 [1]

[debug] QUERY OK source="partitioned_table" db=0.4ms idle=8.5ms
SELECT n0."id" FROM "partitioned_table" AS n0 WHERE (n0."partitioned_key" = $1) LIMIT 1 [1]

[debug] QUERY OK source="partitioned_table" db=7260.7ms idle=8.7ms
SELECT n0."id" FROM "partitioned_table" AS n0 WHERE (n0."partitioned_key" = $1) LIMIT 1 [1]

[debug] QUERY OK source="partitioned_table" db=699.7ms idle=938.4ms
SELECT n0."id" FROM "partitioned_table" AS n0 WHERE (n0."partitioned_key" = $1) LIMIT 1 [1]

[debug] QUERY OK source="partitioned_table" db=707.1ms idle=898.4ms
SELECT n0."id" FROM "partitioned_table" AS n0 WHERE (n0."partitioned_key" = $1) LIMIT 1 [1]
...
```

We're not quite sure why this is happening. We thought the partition table query may have been creating locks that caused problems, but it doesn't seem to create any.

For some context, the partition we queried contains 269321 tuples. Buffers seem to have an effect on benchmark times. The shared buffer size when the test above was run was 128 MB.  When shared buffer size was increased to 4 GB, runtimes did improve.

As well as this, if tests were run a number of times, spikes in runtimes occurred less frequently. This was unexpected as the query only accesses one partition so we thought buffering shouldn't be a factor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated in determining what is likely happening here, thanks!

Comment: The impact of cache may have come from having 2080 similar queries run in a series. Otherwise this question has little chance of a specific solution.

Comment: 128MB for shared buffers is very small for a database where you need a 1000 partitions for a single table. Start with 25% of your available RAM. And what version of PostgreSQL are you using? What OS? Etc etc. Results from explain (analyze,verbose,buffers) for this SQL statement (in plain text) would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your shared buffer is too small, but the main question is what version of *Postgres* do you use? Performance of partitioned tables were too slow in older versions, especially when you have 1000 partitions. If you use older version of posrtgres it could be definitely a problem.

Partitioning performance before *Postgres11* was very limited, that feature was basically in a testing mode before *posrtgres11* and performance was terrible when you had more than 100 partitions, not to mentioned lack of features on partitioned tables.

*Postgres12* made a huge leap in performance in that regard and it scales greatly. It almost have no performance decrease between 100 and 2000 partitions so I suggest to upgrade to *Postgres12* if possible or at least get *Postgres11*, in older versions partitioning do not work properly.